# Any idea why this happens in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the below code in coffeescript after I run these lines the value of str is still "d41d8cd98f00b204". Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

```
dataDict = {email: "johndoe@gmail.com", t:213213.213213}
apiFields = ['email', 'password', 'backup_email', 'firstname', 
             'lastname', 'dob', 'username', 'position', 'industry', 
             'institution', 'verificationcode', 'confirmcode', 
             'signuphost', 'responses', 't']

str = "d41d8cd98f00b204"
for ind in apiFields
  str = str + dataDict[ind] if ind in dataDict
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do:

```
append = dataDict[ind]
str = str + append if append
```

---

What you do compiles to:

```
if (__indexOf.call(dataDict, ind) >= 0) str = str + dataDict[ind];
```

where

```
__indexOf === [].indexOf //Array.prototype's indexOf
```

, and `Array.prototype`'s `indexOf` doesn't work on non-array objects.

Answer (score 2):

I think `in` only works on arrays, try:

```
str = str + dataDict[ind] if dataDict[ind]
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#operators):

> You can use `in` to test for array presence, and `of` to test for JavaScript object-key presence.

`in` is for checking if an element is in an array (just like you use `for ... in` to iterate over an array), if you want to test if a key is in an object you'd use `of` (just like you use `for ... of` to iterate over an object):

```
str = str + dataDict[ind] if ind of dataDict
# -------------------------------^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the expansion of `if ind in dataDict`:

```
if (indexOf.call(dataDict, ind) >= 0) {
  str = str + dataDict[ind];
}
```

Checking `if dataDict.hasOwnProperty(ind)` should get this working.